# How to sort through excel file with multiple blank cells using python

Tags: python, excel

I have been having trouble for a while doing this. I am now learning python and I need help doing this

For example if there is a bunch of data in the file. Imagine a budget spreadsheet where there are multiple blank cells and different sections of the file.

Each section is labeled for example Living expenses, savings, debt. but I only want to go to debt and get the values there are under the debt column. This data may change so I am not looking for a specific ID. I am just looking for the data under debt. There might be 10 rows or 50. How do i do it?

And just for visual sake how Do I do this if debt is around 50,50 (X, Y) on the spreadsheet?

I have tried pandas and openxl.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to delete this but I have found an answer

```
    cell_name = "debt"

# Iterate through all cells to find the matching cell
matching_cell = None
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == cell_name:
            matching_cell = cell
            break
    if matching_cell:
        break

# If a matching cell is found, print the values in the rows below it (up to 10 rows)
if matching_cell:
    column = matching_cell.column
    start_row = matching_cell.row + 1
    end_row = start_row + 10
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).